# Google chart не работает в браузере Safari

Tags: google-api, диаграммы, safari

Вобщем суть проста: есть функция, при активации которой загружаются данные с сервера при помощи аякса в гугл график.
Сам код:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
function showChart(id,obj,dataname,datatype,start,end){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path_to+"ajax.php",
        data: {  
            's': start,
            'e': end,
            'title': id,
            'p': datatype,
            'f': 'crt'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            if(Object.keys(data).length){
                $('#chart_div').css('display','block');
                var chda = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                chda.addColumn('datetime', 'Время');
                chda.addColumn('number', dataname);
                for(i in data) chda.addRow([new Date(data[i]['date']+' '+data[i]['datetime']),parseInt(data[i][datatype])]);

                var options = {
                    title: obj+': '+dataname,
                    vAxis: {minValue: 0},
                    backgroundColor: '#123',
                    areaOpacity: 0.5,
                    theme: 'maximized',
                    hAxis: {
                        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                        title: '',  
                        titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'},
                        gridlines: {
                            count: -1,
                            units: {
                                days: {format: ['MMM dd']},
                                hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']},
                            }
                        },
                        minorGridlines: {
                            units: {
                                hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']},
                                minutes: {format: ['HH:mm a Z', ':mm']}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(chda, options);
                $('#chart_div').css('display','none');
                $('rect').attr('fill','rgba(0,0,0,0.9)');
                $('text').attr('fill','#DBDDDF');
                $('#chart_div').slideToggle('slow').after('<div onClick="$(\'#chart_div\').slideUp(\'slow\');$(this).remove();" id="chartclose" style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;width:50px;height:50px;line-height:50px;font-size:26px;border-radius:50%;border:3px solid #CB9051;background-color:rgb(68, 67, 72);text-align:center;color:orange;">X</div>');
            } else alert('Данных не найдено');
        }
    });
}
```

Во всех браузерах всё работает без проблем, но сафари, как всегда, устраивает мне очередные проблемы. В результате я получаю ошибку: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'new google.visualization.DataTable')`
Понятия не имею, как с этим бороться, гугление не помогло.

Comment: Просто рандомом вставил какой-то код, но Сафари схавал. Вот эта строчка помогла мне загрузить график в сафари: `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>`

Comment: Но теперь сафари не хочет добавлять данные в график и он появляется пустым. Этот сафари прямо второй IE, задолбаешься под него всё перестраивать.